# Json can't parse result from copyManager

Tags: java, json, postgresql

Im trying to export the tables on my Postgres database to json files, everything work normal when I just use `select row_to_json(t) from (SELECT  *  from tableName) t;` but for tables that they have more than 1,6 Million of rows Postgres show an exception of lack of memory.So best solution that I found is to work with copyManager and copy the result directly to the json file using this sql statement `COPY (select row_to_json(t) from (SELECT * from tableName) t) to  STDOUT ;`
my problem is that I have some data with double quotes when using the normal SELECT I get my json file correct and the " are like \"  but using COPY the " are like \\"  or with this I get problem on the JSON parsing cause its not anymore a valid json
below is my code

```
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:/" + tableName + ".json");
        CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager(db.getConnection().unwrap(BaseConnection.class));
        String sql = "COPY (select row_to_json(t) from (SELECT  *  from " + tableName
                + ") t) to  STDOUT ;";
        try {
            copyManager.copyOut(sql, fileWriter);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        } finally {
            fileWriter.close();
        }
```

the error on the parsing is  `Internal error:org.json.simple.parser.ParseException error Unexpected character (f) at position 127.`  and if we look at that position we found

```
"street":"street name \\"first test\\""
```

and this is not a valid json that I can parse it or using `select row_to_json(t) from (SELECT  *  from tableName) t;` I get this

```
"street":"street name \"first test\""
```

and it work perfectly, so how I can fix this this or if there is other methods to export huge tables to json files, thanks

this is the previous code that works :

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
String sql = "select row_to_json(t) from (SELECT  " + columns + "  from " + tableName + ") t) ";
try(Connection con = db.getConnection()){
         try (PreparedStatement stmt = SQL.prepareStatement(db, con, sql);
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                printWriter.print(rs.getString(1));
            }
            stmt.close();
              }
         printWriter.close();
    }
```

Comment: `select row_to_json(t) from (SELECT  *  from tableName) t;`  Why not just `select row_to_json(t) from tableName t;` ?

Comment: "Postgres show an exception of lack of memory."  Postgres throws the exception, or java does?

Comment: Please show the java code that works for your smaller tables.

Comment: cause in some cases I'm using the SELECT for some columns not all, Postgresql throws the exception this is the error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: memory used up Detail: Error when requesting size 536870912.